# ASP.NET Identity authenticate through Web API instead of the default database

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-3

Using ASP.NET Identity can you make calls to a Web API instead of the default database? If so, how would you go about it?

Comment: That is very broad. Check out [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity). You are basically going to need a custom storage provider that would call the web api.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand, you want to use custom database for identity.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- Asp.Net Identity Context -->
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**IdentityModels.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("MyConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
```

and **Update-Database**